# Quartz Scheduler- How to use exclusive resources?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, resource-management

I am investigating whether or not Quartz can be used for a project I am working on. I need to:

1. Limit the execution of jobs to specific time ranges (which I know Quartz is great at).
2. Limit jobs based on "resources".

When I say resources, I referring to both exclusive and quantitative resources. For example, I would like to define a resource something like "LINUX_MACHINE" with a count of 5. Only a maximum of 5 jobs requiring the LINUX_MACHINE machine resource can be run at any one time. Is this possible to do using Quartz?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you can limit jobs based on resources by creating multiple schedulers and then limiting the thread pool for each scheduler.

Info on multiple schedulers: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers

Info on Quartz config to set the thread pool for the scheduler: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool